# not receiving any response from fetch() API

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I've defined a script which on first click on a 'button' makes some content editable and on second click runs a function which uses fetch() to send data to php.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
                let maximum=parseInt(<?php echo $incremental; ?>);
                let makeMod;
                let action;
                for (let i = 1; i<=maximum; i++) {
                    action=1;
                    document.getElementById('button-' + i).addEventListener("click", dothis);
                    function dothis() {                 
                        if (action==1) {
                            makeMod = document.getElementById('TipoInt-' + i);
                            makeMod.contentEditable = true;
                            makeMod.focus();
                            makeMod.style.backgroundColor = '#E0E0E0';
                            makeMod.style.border = '1px dotted black';
                            action = 2;
                        } else {
                            let IDActivity = (document.getElementById('IDAct-' + i).innerHTML);
                            let Place = (document.getElementById('PlaceAct-' + i).innerHTML);
                            let DateActivity = (document.getElementById('DateAct-' + i).innerHTML);
                            let Activity_Type= (document.getElementById('TypeAct-' + i).innerHTML);
                            let Actor1= (document.getElementById('Ac1Int-' + i).innerHTML);
                            let Actor2= (document.getElementById('Ac2Int-' + i).innerHTML);
                            function sendData() {
                                let data = {
                                    IDActivity : IDActivity,
                                    Place : Place,
                                    DateActivity : DateActivity,
                                    Activity_Type : Activity_Type,
                                    Actor1 : Actor1,
                                    Actor2 : Actor2
                                };

                                fetch("DBEdit.php", {
                                    method: "POST",
                                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                                    headers: {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                    },
                                })

                                .then((response) => response.text())
                                .then((data) => alert(data));
                            };

                            action = 1;
                        };
                    };
                };
    }
</script>
```

The script works fine if I use, for example, alert() instead of the function sendData(),
but with the function sendData() I don't receive the expected response.
In the DBEdit.php I have the following php code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

echo $data["IDActivity"];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $data["DateActivity"];
?>
```

Comment: I can't find any error in the js console. The Network tab only contains two get lines: jquery and bootstrap...

Comment: You don't call the sendData function anywhere. (Why is it even a function?)

Comment: Open dev tools and click network tab